# Why is my HTTPS re-direct slowing down my website? .htaccess code wrong?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, seo, web-deployment

As you can see from the image below the Google speed test is showing my HTTPS redirect as an error. I guess there's one too many re-directs going on? I'm unfamiliar with the code in the htaccess file, so I'm hoping someone can help me. I switched out my actual domain with EXAMPLE. I assume this is causing my website all sorts of issues with its SEO.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.EXAMPLE.com/$1 [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

EDIT: I think it may have been because this in wpconfig:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://www.EXAMPLE.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'https://www.EXAMPLE.com');
```

I removed the www

Was that the issue?

[Google Speed test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujy7F.png)

Comment: The double redirection shown in that analysis is not caused by the rules you posted. The first rule redirects to "www.EXAMPLE.com", but that is not what is shown in the anlysis. So something else is responsible for that redirection. So some other redirection is applied by some other rule, explicit or implicit. You will need to find that rule, but it is not within that configuration file you posted.

Comment: if you are testing an http url without www then you will get redirects and that warning. Ideally you want the one redirect so everything should be pointing to https://www. As @arkascha pointed out, it looks like something else is doing a straight http to https redirect before your code gets a look in. Maybe at the hosting or CDN level?